# diaspora autofollow on join not working on heroku pod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, diaspora

I had a working diaspora pod on heroku from past 3 months every thing is working fine accept the auto follow on join functionality. I had set my own account to follow and its working but new users on my pod are not getting my old post. Anyone know what I am doing wrong..??

Comment: Just to confirm, by "people are not getting my post" you mean people joining your pod? Maybe they have stopped following you since joining? Have you tested the auto follow on join works by creating a second account and verifying the new account follows your primary account?

Comment: i had tested it @jaywink . And yeah am talking about the people joining my pod. when i go to the primamry account it says Shadab is not sharing with you (my primary account is shadab)

Comment: @jaywink i had editted my question actully my new users are unable to see my old posts what to do any help...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On diaspora*, when a user shares with another user, that user will only be able to see any limited posts from this point onwards, not any previously posted posts. The reason for this is simple. Since a limited post in history was never shared with the new connection, it is not visible.

It is not possible to edit the visibility of old posts. If you want to write posts that new connections also see, they should be made as public posts.

[More on aspects and visibility](https://iliketoast.net/help/aspects).